# my login script fails at verifying the hashed password

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I'am making a login screen for my blog but when it checks if the password you set in the input field is the same as the hashed password in the database he is saying that my password is wrong when it isn't.

I've googled a long time now and asks a couple of class mates but it still doesn't work.

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="?page=blogInput">
            <br><h1>LOGIN</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" maxlength="24"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="8"
                   maxlength="16"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="login" id="submit">
        </form>
  <?php
include_once('resources/db.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username,));
$saved_password = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['password'];

if (isset($username, $password)){
    if (password_verify($password, $saved_password)){
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> location.href='register.php' </script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong username!')</script>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong password or username!')</script>";
    }

}else{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('You need to fill in all fields')</script>";
}

?>
```

It is know edited as the last comment suggested.

Comment: The way you're doing your PDO queries are vulnerable to SQL Injection, Use placeholders instead.

Comment: I see a `prepare()` call but you never `execute()` the statement. You should be replacing `'$username'` with a parameter `:username` in the SQL and calling `$query->execute(array(':username' => $username))` before attempting to fetch.

Comment: Are you getting the hash that you are expecting when you `echo $saved_password` ?

Comment: First you need to actually execute the query, but you also need to drop the  `and password='$password'` part of the query.

Comment: Did i edit the code you suggested right?

Comment: that went from `'$vars'` to `':vars'` well that's failing either way

Comment: The overall logic doesn't make any sense. If passwords are hashed, you cannot find by plain text passwords.

Comment: You're almost there - you need to remove the quotes from `':username'`, should only be `:username` unquoted in the SQL.  But  I did not see the first time `:password` is also in the query. Remove that. You need to query by username only.

Comment: I don't know php very well so I don't know how it should be. I would appreciate if someone could write an example for me.

Comment: I added your changes Michael but now I don't even get the alert

Comment: wondering also if `password_hash()` was originally used

Comment: how do you mean

Comment: @Fred-ii- is asking, when you inserted the passwords in the database initially, did you hash them using the password hash function? In other words, if you echo out a saved password, does it give you a string that resembles: `$2y$10$cSduc..zPecSHY.THB0gMu2SUhDAs3ImQSACWhTYykjO7NUVEEJq.`

Comment: I made a registration form and that's working fine.                       $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password
    $hash_password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

Comment: @LucasKrupinski I'd go over ^ - also the multiple edits.

Comment: I go over them again and again but can't get anything new out of that sorry.

Comment: this question requires a total rewrite for both hashing and verifying.

Comment: @C.Schotman - So you're saying you're making up your own method of salting and hashing the password, rather than using `password_hash()`? That would mean the `password_verify()` method will be unable to verify it.

Comment: I did rewrite everything a couple of times but it didn't work so if you can help me with the next try it would be amazing.

Comment: I'm not going to do a complete rewrite. Read the manuals and tutorials; you can't mix different hashing methods.

Comment: @Lucas Krupinski - I found the code like that and I changed a little bit to add to my code but thanks.

Comment: Throw away your salt and hash function. Just take the password the user provides as $password and use `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` and insert that in your user database. Then compare against that hash when you use password_verify() later on

Comment: I replaced my salt and put there the password_hash but I still can't login

Comment: I would suggest closing this question and creating a new question so we can see what you're working with. 

Include both the user insert function and the validation function

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks `$password` twice. First in the query it checks if the password matches. Then, it checks if the hash of the password matches *the same value*.

Just remove the `and password=` nonsense from your database query, and finish correcting the parameter inputs as mentioned in comments. You should be fine.

---

... I just noticed...

```
SELECT username FROM ...
```

**You aren't selecting the password (hash) from the database!**

```
SELECT `password` FROM ...
```

Comment: is this what you mend? I've got the alerts back now but it's still not logging in

Comment: The OP is editing on the fly and now their query doesn't make any sense at all. Edit: It has undergone quite a few revisions http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43559298/revisions - Edit #2: It has now undergone yet another edit.

Comment: thats very good possible but I don't know how i have to do it so I do what I understand you all say I must do.

Comment: as far as I know I did everything you all suggested but it still says that my username or password is wrong.

Comment: Niet; you need to go over new comments under the question. This question will remain unsolved and your answer no longer applies.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the heads-up. Spotted something new.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think you should go over comments again; they used a different hashing method and I had a feeling about that, which is why I asked them if they used `password_hash()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah. Yes, I see... To be honest the whole question could do with deleting and re-asking properly...

Comment: I don't know what you mean